# Change configuration options for specific files only

Tags: doxygen

I'm working on a small part of a huge project. I need to change some Doxygen configuration options only for specific files. For example, there is such configuration option DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES and its default value is 50. I need to increase its value to 100 but only for some source files (for all other source files it should be 50). What is the the best way to achieve it?

I'm a newbie in Doxygen and I tried to @include my configuration file on a top of .cpp or try to set a new value to an option there as well but it did not help (but did not cause any warnings or errors):

```
/// @include MyDoxyfile
//  or
/// DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES = 10000
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

In doxygen the `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` is a global setting and cannot be altered. This contrary to some graphs that can be shown / hidden:

> • if CALL_GRAPH is set to YES, a graphical call graph is drawn for
>   each function showing the functions that the function directly or
>   indirectly calls (see also section \callgraph and section
>   \hidecallgraph).
>
> • if CALLER_GRAPH is set to YES, a graphical caller
>   graph is drawn for each function showing the functions that the
>   function is directly or indirectly called by (see also section
>   \callergraph and section \hidecallergraph).

and in the upcoming 1.8.15 version a similar mechanism is implemented for

- `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION`, commands: `showrefby` and `hiderefby`
- `REFERENCES_RELATION`, commands: `showrefs` and `hiderefs`